# egrep search: every letter appears maximum 2 times

Tags: regex, expression, md5, grep

Ok, I've got this issue where I have a list of md5's and a word next to it separated with a space, and I need to filter out some lines.

Example snippet:

```
...
F08A4C9263AD215D70B9C216F0B385CB wrapup
7B286E6F0615D64ACD4A7BC3578871DD wrath
8E35BA3D27A7730840EB1694386F69A0 wrathful
096762EA6790EDA22BF2369347FD53AC wreak
56AC6677205EB591A7173BADBB610F5C wreath
A85C0CB6C0367AF9D23442DF56EC9E1C wreathe
9E44AAE612306D44B91C4162DB5C26B7 wreck
6D9C795CBB3075DC1A482F6F78DC6D68 wreckage
BD907BC4DC65934D133BD5C472B78CC0 wrench
758C70E9B6F437D49D98D92E28E95939 wrest
81A4471F73DFDA0B534F58F4E1501FAB wrestle
94183CC7C7A66338DE89DB9C7460A8A2 wretch
AFEED5CE5BACCEC17EC54E68A97CCD0F wriggle
...
```

I need a regular expression **for (e)grep** that pulls out every line where every letter (so [A-F]) appears only 2 times maximum.
so an example for that would be:

```
4F2048B829C2834A23832F28928DE38E turtle
```

If anyone can help me with this i'd appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
egrep -v "^\S*([A-F])\S*\1\S*\1" inputfile
```

That would list every line which does not include the letters A-F repeated three times in the same line.

EDIT: changed to avoid matching uppercase characters in the words...

Comment: It'd be more rigorous to limit the characters to the hash only - so that even when the text changes and contains uppercase character, the command still works.

Comment: Which is easy to fix; require a space somewhere after the last match, or change the skips to only skip non-space characters.

Comment: I'd use this `egrep -v '^[0-9A-F]*([A-F])[0-9A-F]*\1[0-9A-F]*\1' inputfile`, but the assumptions you made is fair enough.

Comment: Perfect beny! This is what i'm looking for! tyvm (i'd up your answer but i can't lol)

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned:

> pulls out every line where every letter (so [A-F]) appears only 2
>   times maximum.

So my understanding is, the selected line should contain 0-2 [A-F]. Based on this, the following awk oneliner should do the job:

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=""}{delete a;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/[A-F]/){a[$i]++;if(a[$i]>2)next}}1' file
```

Test

Note, the given input has **NO** line satisfies your requirement. So I added the 'turtle' line at the end:

```
kent$  echo "F08A4C9263AD215D70B9C216F0B385CB wrapup
7B286E6F0615D64ACD4A7BC3578871DD wrath
8E35BA3D27A7730840EB1694386F69A0 wrathful
096762EA6790EDA22BF2369347FD53AC wreak
56AC6677205EB591A7173BADBB610F5C wreath
A85C0CB6C0367AF9D23442DF56EC9E1C wreathe
9E44AAE612306D44B91C4162DB5C26B7 wreck
6D9C795CBB3075DC1A482F6F78DC6D68 wreckage
BD907BC4DC65934D133BD5C472B78CC0 wrench
758C70E9B6F437D49D98D92E28E95939 wrest
81A4471F73DFDA0B534F58F4E1501FAB wrestle
94183CC7C7A66338DE89DB9C7460A8A2 wretch
AFEED5CE5BACCEC17EC54E68A97CCD0F wriggle
4F2048B829C2834A23832F28928DE38E turtle"|awk  'BEGIN{FS=""}{delete a;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/[A-F]/){a[$i]++;if(a[$i]>2)next}}1'                          
4F2048B829C2834A23832F28928DE38E turtle
```